# using retr from perl script - 'RETR' not understood

Tags: perl, ftp

I have a simple Task, In my company we need to download files from ftp server, normaly i've got some scripts and they can handle with this, but on one server i have some problems. When i use system specific ftp command it works fine the file can be downloaded, but when i try to do this from perl I get error "'RETR' not understood".

My scripts looks like this

shell:

`ftp> debug

ftp> open xx.xx.xx.xx

220 ProFTPD 1.3.0 Server (ProFTPD Default Installation) [xx.xx.xx.xx]

ftp> cd IN

---> CWD IN

250 CWD command successful

ftp> get somefile10112499xxx.ZIP

---> PORT 3,126,181,35,14,131

200 PORT command successful

---> RETR somefile10112499xxx.ZIP

150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for somefile10112499xxx.ZIP (13299 bytes)

226 Transfer complete.

ftp: 64d bajtów odebranych w 0,01Sekund 889,80Kbajtów/sek.

ftp> quit

---> QUIT

221 Goodbye.`


perl script:

`use Net::FTP;

$ftp = Net::FTP->new($FTP_HOST, Debug => 1,Passive=>0) ;

$ftp->login($FTP_USER,$FTP_PASS) ;

$ftp->retr("somefile10112499xxx.ZIP");

$ftp->quit;`


I try with passive mode, ascii and binary transmission method, but all of this make "Net::FTP=GLOB(0x1ee71a0)<<< 500 'RETR' not understood".

Are there any others parameters define by default in command ftp? Maybe i should make some changes in perl script?

Comment: Off-topic, but I'm thinking facepalm when I see someone download a `*.ZIP` file in `ASCII mode`.

Comment: offcourse that it should be a binary mode, but this is'nt the problem - I want the simplest sample to show that this works.

Comment: In the first example you don't appear to be logging in, but in the Net::FTP example you're logging in?

Comment: 2006 called, they want their [buggy](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2006-5815) FTP server software. Notify the FTP admin to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Is there are reason you're using `$ftp->retr()` instead of `$ftp->get()` for downloading these files?  Generally with [Net::Ftp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aFTP) if you're just downloading files you use the

```
get ( REMOTE_FILE [, LOCAL_FILE [, WHERE]] )
```

method.  I believe `retr()` method returns a reference to a `Net::FTP::dataconn` object.

Comment: what do you get if you do:      $ftp->get("somefile..") or die "get failed ", $ftp->message;

Comment: Have you tried it without the debug flag set?  If all you need to do is download the file, I can't see why you would need debug set.

Comment: One would imagine that he has the debug flag set because he wants to find out why downloading the file isn't working...

Comment: Perhaps, but I have seen plenty of people who set debug flags even when they don't need the extra information.

Comment: I used the debug mode to show what server is reposnding to me.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to know about FTP is that there is a client program and a server program. The client program takes one set of commands and the server takes another set of *site* commands. Your client might take RETR and turn it into something the remote server knows. That *500* you're getting back is from there server. So regardless of whether or not your local client knows what the server will take for 'RETR' it does not appear that the server understands that command. That is what it is telling you.

It's been a while since I cracked open `Net::FTP`, but if I can remember a lot of the less frequent commands get passed to the server.

Comment: It could be, do you know some other package to handle ftp? I allways use this one.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, problem wasn't in the downloading script but it was on FTP server. The file was deleted from the server - was some kind of crash  - and that is why i couldn't download it.

Afterall, it seems that in script sometimes i was using get method without any arguments, and this also returned `500 'RETR' not understood`. I think that is not cool, it should tell me that there isn't such file.

But i want to thank you people for reading and helping.